# Unregistered action (via custom module) leads to XSRF Attack Detected error

Tags: php, html, csrf, sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 8.0.1, I am trying to make a new, unregistered action work.

The action is a form and has been added to my custom module. I am trying to reach it from itself in the following manner so that on form submission, the form-data is sent back to itself (aka, the `action` link leads back to the same page the form is on):

```
<form method="POST" name="ConfigureSettings" action="#bwc/index.php?module=CustomModule&action=newAction">
```

Based on [SugarCRM Support's Troubleshooting Cross-Site Forgery Messages](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting_Cross-Site_Forgery_Messages/), the way to add an additional action is as follows:

> To add the unregistered action as an allowed action (e.g. custom
>   module), add the following line of code to the `config_override.php`
>   file:
>
> ```
> $sugar_config['http_referer']['actions'] =array( 'index', 'ListView', 'DetailView', 'EditView', 'oauth', 'authorize', 'Authenticate', 'Login', 'SupportPortal', 'bad_action' );
> ```

Doing this alone does not work, and trying to save my changes or cancel editing my form will still lead to the same error:

```
Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Attack Detected
Form authentication failure (CustomModule -> newAction). Contact your administrator.
```

Is there something I have to edit in the `$sugar_config` to relate it to my specific action? I tried changing `bad_action` to `newAction`, but to no avail.

---

Found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526161/sugarcrm-8-xsrf) which will just log the error rather than abort the action, and it proves that my form is working correctly in which I am led back to the same page and the form has been updated.

Unfortunately, this is not a solution to my problem because this is unsafe for a production instance, and I am still not sure why I'm getting the error in the first place as I am not redirecting to a site outside of the instance.

Comment: This is a BWC form, right? Did you add the csrf token to your form as described at the bottom on https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer/blog/2015/12/01/csrf-tokens-in-sugar-77?

Comment: Correct. I had not tried that yet. Am I not supposed to add it verbatim? I added `{sugar_csrf_form_token}` to a line underneath my `<form ...>` line, and nothing changed; still getting the XSRF error.

Comment: Does it show up differently in the actual source received by the browser? I don't have any experience with this, so I'm not smarter than the documentation, sorry.

Comment: Probably irrelevant side-note: In the form snippet you posted, the `&` does *not* appear to be properly html-escaped as `&amp;`

Comment: Good catch on `&`, though this is how it was written in Sugar 7.8.2.2 and it worked fine then. Updated to `&amp;` and tried all methods I have previously went through again, and still nothing. Looking into the actual source received by the browser; not exactly sure how to go about trying this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the HTML form needs to be separated from the PHP file by using a Template file and Smarty tags to replace the instances of PHP in the Template file.

Did the above, then included the `{sugar_csrf_form_token}` mentioned [here](https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer/blog/2015/12/01/csrf-tokens-in-sugar-77) in the Template file, and its working correctly now.