# Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Attack Detected sugar 8.2

Tags: sugarcrm

Sugar Version - SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 8.2.0 (Build 139) (Fall '18)

I've a local copy of sugar instance it works fine if I'm creating record or updating or anything.

When I try to go in Studio it is throwing following error

```
Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Attack Detected
Form authentication failure (ModuleBuilder -> wizard). Contact your 
administrator.
```

I've followed [Troubleshooting Cross-Site Forgery Messages](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting_Cross-Site_Forgery_Messages/)

And this [Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Attack Detected - SugarCRM 7.9 restrictions](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/30915-cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-attack-detected-sugarcrm-79-restrictions)

And this too [Sugarcrm 8 XSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526161/sugarcrm-8-xsrf) which was my question long ago but was solved but it's not related to this

I've tried to add my hostnames in http_referer but it's not working. I tried everything but I'm not even getting different error message.
Though my old sugar instance which have version 8.0 works fine but I'm having problem for newer version.

Comment: @Jay any suggestion on this?

Comment: It does sound like a form token issue. Can you look for "CSRF:" messages in your sugarcrm.log please? `grep -i '[cx]srf' sugarcrm.log`
It should tell you whether the token was missing or wrong - or if there was another problem.

Comment: @Jay It is saying "attack vector detected, invalid form token detected". If I open console and go to network to that request I can see token there. Just tell me I've currently two instance setup on local 8.0 and 8.2 is this problem? But I've checked in incognito too even another browser but I'm facing same error.

Comment: @intrajeet I'm not too familiar with 8.2 so I can only give generic advice at the moment.

As you're running more than one instance, make sure **not** to use the same `unique_key` or `site_url` in their config.php. If you change any of those delete `cache/` contents and do a Quick Repair and Rebuild.

Comment: @Jay Yes, site_url are different already. I've also tried deleting contents of cache folder but it doesn't work.

Comment: PS: Additional to Incognito mode, do this: In the Dev Tools of your Browser go to -> Application -> Delete all Data, to make sure all Cache, Cookies, App Storage, etc. gets wiped.

By the way. You only need this for local development, don't you? Why not just disable XSRF check entirely? In source if necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to disable XSRF check entirely? how tell me please as I'm only testing it locally.

Comment: Um, I guess you could just insert the line `return true;` as **first** line in the body of the function `checkHTTPReferer` (for skipping referer checks) in `include/MVC/SugarApplication.php` and also in the function `isFormTokenValid` in `src/Security/Csrf/CsrfAuthenticator.php` (for skipping form token checks).
 Note: I didn't test that myself yet.
 PS: If you use a code versioning system like SVN/HG/GIT make sure to not commit those changes by accident. (maybe add the files to your personal gitignore: `.git/info/exclude`)

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the delay, this works perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

inserted into your form this snip:

```
{sugar_csrf_form_token}
```

See here:
https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2015/12/01/csrf-tokens-in-sugar-7-7/

Comment: kindly consider adding the relevant parts in your answer, it is helpful in case the link is removed or changed

Comment: I'm sorry. But the solution be work 100%. I tried it last week.

Comment: @Hisu This was already there in code, as it is part of core page. Also I'm not using older version of sugar for older versions before 8.2 it's working fine the problem is there only for specific version 8.2 I also have older versions like 8.1,8.0 it is working fine there. I appreciate your help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I happen to run SuiteCRM behind an apache2 proxy which does the:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
```

This means that the clients would not send the referer header to SuiteCRM, and, unfortunately, this is needed for the system to function properly.

So, to solve the issue, I had to change that apache2 directive to the following:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy same-origin
```